# How to show error messages under the field in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I show form errors under the fields instead of the top of the form?

How I can make something like this:

```
<%= text_input u, :username %>
```

to render something like this, if there is an error in this field ->

```
<div class="field-with-error">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="error">This username is already taken</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The errors are all in the errors field of the form struct, so you can typically access them as `f.errors`. Here is an example:

```
<%= if message = f.errors[:username] do %>
  <span><%= translate_error(message) %></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 10):

Now you can use:

```
<%= error_tag f, :firstname %>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple helper method to deal with this problem ->

```
def render_form_field(type, form, field, options \\ []) do
  form_field = apply(Phoenix.HTML.Form, type, [form, field, options]) 

  if form.errors[field] do
   wrapper_class = "input field-with-errors"
   error = content_tag(:span, form.errors[field], class: "error")
   content_tag(:div, [form_field, error], class: wrapper_class)
  else
   wrapper_class = "input"
   content_tag(:div, form_field, class: wrapper_class)
  end
end
```

I have obviously hardcoded a few things here but that'll do for an example

and then in the template you simple do the following ->

```
<%= render_form_field :text_input, u, :username, placeholder: "blah blah" %>
```